Queried value of Auto_increment stops updating
It continues to work fine and can even be changed manually with the "ALTER TABLE" command (can detect this by inserting new rows and looking at their ids), but its queried value never updates.
Example queries:
SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'WorkOrderTblNew';
gives value of 6253
SELECT MAX(WorkOrderID) FROM WorkOrderTblNew;
also gives value of 6253
After inserting a new row (leaving out id since it is set to auto increment), the "show table status" query still returns  6253 but there is now a row with id=6254.
ALTER TABLE WorkOrderTblNew AUTO_INCREMENT = 6260;
makes it start adding new rows at id=6260, with the next after that being 6261 so the actual auto increment value is being set but the value displayed by the "SHOW TABLE STATUS..." query is now completely disconnected from it.
I've had this occasionally happen over the course of several versions of mysql. Any idea what causes it?

What do you mean by "query is now completely disconnected from it"?

I run this: SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'database_name' AND TABLE_NAME = 'WorkOrderTblNew'; and it keeps showing the same value regardless of what AUTO_INCREMENT is set to via inserting rows or using "ALTER TABLE WorkOrderTblNew AUTO_INCREMENT =".  Based on values of new "id" fields, it is still otherwise working properly.
Another variation of this is AUTO_INCREMENT always displaying one less than its actual value, but this isn't what is happening right now.  The 2 fixes I have used is to reinstall mysql or disable auto increment for that table.

Answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57383942/20860

It looks like my issue was a special case of the one linked to by Bill Karwin.
I ran this
SET GLOBAL information_schema_stats_expiry = 0;
SET LOCAL information_schema_stats_expiry = 0;
and verified with
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'information_schema_stats_expiry';.
Then AUTO_INCREMENT in information_schema started showing the correct value.
Thanks!
